# When adding a user to a role in asp.net mvc 4.5, i'm getting an error- "user (user name) not found"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my account login controller. (My "auth" class method returns "user" or "admin" and is logged in accordingly).

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string userName, string pass)
    {
        Auth auth = new Auth();
        if (auth.MyAuth(userName) == "user")
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        else if(auth.MyAuth(userName) == "admin")
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
            if (!Roles.RoleExists("admin"))
            {
                Roles.CreateRole("admin");
            }
            if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, "admin"))
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, "admin");
            }

            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

**Edited**

```
public class Auth 
{ 
  public string MyAuth(string userName) 
  { if (userName.Length == 4) 
     { return "user"; } 
    else if (userName.Length == 5) 
      { return "admin"; } 
    return "unauth"; } }
```

The problem is when I add a user with Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, "admin"), I get an error that it cannot find user(userName). I'm at a loss as to why!

Here's the role manager details from web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
<providers>
<add name="DefaultRoleProvider" 
  type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers,
  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
  connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
</providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: public class Auth
    {
       public string MyAuth(string userName)
       {
           if (userName.Length == 4)
           {
               return "user";
           }
           else if (userName.Length == 5)
           {
               return "admin";
           }
           return "unauth";
       }
    }

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.adduserstoroles(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My bad, I posted wrong link. This is the proper link for addusertorole which accepts two strings. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.security.roles.addusertorole(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=I8WIVZuFIIHm-AGjvKCQBw&usg=AFQjCNH5vOWVez0eodHWANVxmaruOhx7gQ&sig2=_GVDpCeGxJwHj6mijlwhKQ

Comment: r u sure the error is coming at `Roles.AddUserToRoleusers(users,roles)`?

Comment: Yes! User xyz not found.

Comment: can you post the rolemanager details in webconfig file?

Comment: change your `<rolemanager>` to `<roleManager
    enabled="true"
    cacheRolesInCookie="true"
    cookieName=".ASPXROLES"
    cookieTimeout="30"
    cookiePath="/"
    cookieRequireSSL="false"
    cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
    cookieProtection="All"
    defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
    createPersistentCookie="false"
    maxCachedResults="25" />` this and try..hope it helps

Comment: comment it and use the above code and try..

Comment: Thank you man it works! If I could hug you I would!

Comment: :) u r welcome..will post it as answer...mark it if helped..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not setting roleManager properly in webconfig.
change your webconfig as below.

```
 <roleManager enabled="true" 
cacheRolesInCookie="true" 
cookieName=".ASPXROLES" 
cookieTimeout="30" 
cookiePath="/" 
cookieRequireSSL="false" 
cookieSlidingExpiration="true" 
cookieProtection="All" 
defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
 createPersistentCookie="false" maxCachedResults="25" />
```